# Python dataframe import matching column and index data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master data frame and auxiliary data frame. Both have the same timestamp index and columns with master having few more columns. I want to copy a certain column's data from aux to master.

My code:

```
maindf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.0,NaN],'B':[10,20],'C':[100,200],},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=2))
auxdf= pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[30,40],},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=2))

maindf = 
                       A   B    C
2020-05-04 08:00:00  0.0  10  100
2020-05-04 09:00:00  NaN  20  200

auxdf = 
                     A   B
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1  30
2020-05-04 09:00:00  2  40
```

**Expected answer:** I want o take column A data in auxdf and copy to maindf by matching the index.

```
maindf = 
                     A   B    C
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1  10  100
2020-05-04 09:00:00  2  20  200
```

**My solution:**

```
maindf['A'] = auxdf['A']
```

My solution is not correct because I am copying values directly without checking for matching index. how do I achieve the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html), as follows:

```
maindf['A'].update(auxdf['A'])
```

[`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) uses non-NA values from passed Series to make updates. Aligns on index.

Note also that the original dtype of `maindf['A']` is retained:  remains as `float` type even when `auxdf['A']` is of `int` type.

Result:

```
print(maindf)

                       A   B    C
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1.0  10  100
2020-05-04 09:00:00  2.0  20  200
```

Comment: so, `.update()` replaces all values in maindf whether they are nan, or floats with the values from auxdf. Right?

Comment: @Mainland  It updates only matching index / indexes (row and column indexes for dataframe).   One point to note is that it takes only non-NA value from the auxiliary df / series.

Comment: @Mainland  You can refer to the link I provided above for `Series.update()` for more examples on Series operations.  Also see the doc for [`DataFrame.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) for examples for dataframe.